# Count total number of True and False with two dates criteria range in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have to count the total number of true and false between two dates. Can anyone help me with that.

Here is the data looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Fw1.png)

Here is how I need to gain data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgO79.png)

Please help me with that.. Here is the link to the sheet: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uI988k4knx9dRIpcQx3WP6gD5PV8s1LC2VB5Up6kHq8/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(Data!B:B, Data!A:A>=$A3, Data!A:A<=$B3, Data!B:B=TRUE)))
```

[image]